# PHP preg_match() and wordpress single quote in editor bug

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-match

I messed up with one of my code in functions.php, can someone tell me what this line does?

```
$output = preg_match_all(''/<img.+src=[''"]([^''"]+)[''"].*>/i'', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. That code above was affected by that bug in Wordpress that makes single quotes `'` become `''` when saved (that Wordpress editor at the WP backend).

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line finds all src="..." tags for images. The regular expression literally says " or ', followed by anything that is not ' or ", followed by another ' or ".

To fix it:

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

Comment: Were you trying to use vb.net style escaping?

Comment: @jakx nope. This I accidentally edited some code on a Wordpress template. (PHP)